# Add-In tab not displayed after adding add-in in Excel 365

Tags: excel, office365, excel-365

I have Excel 365 64 bit and I'm trying to add an old add-in. In previous versions of Excel when I added my Add-In ([Duplicate Master V2 by brettdj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641067/brettdj)) it would create a new tab labeled Add-In and there would appear the routine. I've tried adding on my new Office 365 Excel Add-in, but I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Did you unblock the add-in in File Explorer?

Comment: If you mean the Excel File Block settings it is empty.

Comment: No, I mean right-click the file in Explorer, choose Properties, and look for an option/button to unblock it. Then restart Excel.

Comment: Oh. I just saw what you meant. Never in a million years would I thought that. Please add as answer to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the file in Explorer, choose Properties, and look for an option/button to unblock it. Then restart Excel. You should then see the AddIns tab hopefully!